# Loss of posted data using Firefox/IE, Safari works

Tags: html, forms, post

I'm debugging a php-script and I have narrowed it to:

```
index.php:
<html>
<body>
<?php
$id = "42";
echo "<form action=\"handle_data.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<input type=\"image\" src=\"my_button.png\" name=\"id\" value=\"$id\">";
echo "</form>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

_

```
handle_data.php:
<?php

echo 'PHP Input:<br />';
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
echo '<br />';
echo 'Post variables:<br />';
print_r($_POST);

?>
```

Using Safari on a Mac or a iOS-device works well:

```
PHP Input:
id.x=108&id.y=83&id=42
Post variables:
Array ( [id_x] => 108 [id_y] => 83 [id] => 42 )
```

But, using Win7 with IE8 or Firefox 17, posted data '42' is lost =/

```
PHP Input:
id.x=128&id.y=96
Post variables:
Array ( [id_x] => 128 [id_y] => 96 )
```

Why oh why?

Comment: please show us the complete form code. your code seems not showing all the fields received by the PHP script

Comment: My code above is the complete code! Not working for Firefox nor IE but works for Safari. If I manage the code above to work it will probably work well for my larger implementation...

Comment: Are you clicking on the image to submit the form?

Comment: Yes. index.php and handle_data.php described above is exactly what I have on the server. Nothing more nothing less...

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog](http://blog.lexity.com/blog/2011/6/18/input-typeimage-considered-harmful.html) Firefox and IE are following the HTML5 standard. It provides a CSS alternative.

Change your `input` element to:

```
<input type='submit' name='id' value='$id' class='mySubmit' />
```

and add the CSS:

```
input.mySubmit {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -3000px;
  background: url(my_button.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Tried for a while but didn't get it to work. I've solved it by passing the variable with a link instead: echo "<a href=\"handle_data.php?id=$id\"><img src=\"my_button.png\"></a>"; and then in the handle_data.php I used $_GET[id] instead of $_POST. Hepp...